# Push forward of the structure sheaf along covering

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a covering (proper, surjective, finite regular map) of smooth projective varieties of degree $d$. How one can show that in this case $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $d$?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer relies on the following  incredibly general and simple result:

> Given a finite morphism of schemes $f:X\to Y$ with $Y$ locally noetherian, the sheaf $f_*\mathcal O_X$ is locally trivial iff $f$ is flat.

The proof  consists in quoting a result in commutative algebra: a module $M$ over a ring $R$ is flat of finite presentation iff it is finitely generated and projective
[cf. Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra, Chapter II, §5.3, Corollary 2, page 111]

Once more Mumford's brilliant aphorism applies:

> Flatness is a riddle that comes out of algebra , but which technically is the answer to many prayers.

If $Y$ is smooth, any finite surjective morphism is flat and the above applies, so that $f_*\mathcal O_X$ is locally free, just as you wished.

**Edit**
The last assertion is a particular case of a wonderful result, aptly named by some geometers *miracle flatness*. It goes like this:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism between varieties over a field,  with $X$ Cohen-Macaulay (for example regular) and $Y$ regular. If all fibers of $f$ are of the same dimension, then $f$ is flat.

A reference for this theorem is [GÖRTZ-WEDHORN](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEYQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2Fbfm%253A978-3-8348-9722-0%252F1.pdf&ei=j0gEVMuIA8bfatidgoAF&usg=AFQjCNHwKVJnThxNDpt3W0-4p5kTuUK_sg&sig2=sjnzN_OEyXPE94vzKX-DnQ), Corollary 14.128, page 475.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please add explanation or reference to "if $Y$ is smooth, any finite surjective morphism is flat"?

Comment: Dear Alex, I have added an edit with a generalization and a reference.

Answer (score 7):

With your assumptions, $f$ is a flat morhism, and $H^1(X_y,\mathscr O_{X_y})=0$ for all $y\in Y$. Then the theory of cohomology and base change says that $f_\ast\mathscr O_X$ is locally free. It is rank $d$ because $d=h^0(X_y,\mathscr O_{X_y})$.

If you want a precise statement, here it is:

> Suppose you have a proper morphism $f:X\to Y$, with $Y$ locally
>   Noetherian, and a coherent $\mathscr O_X$-module $\mathscr F$, flat
>   over $Y$. If $R^if_\ast\mathscr F=0$ for all $i\neq 0$, then
>   $f_\ast\mathscr F$ is locally free.