# Can the local freeness of $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ imply the fiber has the same number of points for a finite morphism $f$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a surjective finite (=closed map+fiber finite) holomorphic map between two connected complex manifolds.
Assume  $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $m$.

> **Ques:  can we get that
> $f^{-1}(y)$ contains $m$ points for any $y\in Y$?** (If not, one can add as many conditions as one want)

In some sense the inverse seems to be right:  an analytic **covering map** seems to satisfy the condition  that $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is a locally free, see [Push forward of the structure sheaf along covering](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909013/push-forward-of-the-structure-sheaf-along-covering)

As well known, if $f$ is a proper modification (e.g. blow-up), then  $f_* \mathcal{O}_X= \mathcal{O}_Y$.
But  $f^{-1}(y)$ contains infinitely many  points for some $y$ in the center of $f$. So the finite condition seems to be important,
but I don't know how to use this condition.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions you have listed so far are not yet sufficient: consider $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ by $z\mapsto z^n$ for any integer $n>1$. The preimage of any point that's not $0$ is $n$ points, while $0$ has one preimage. This map is *ramified* at $0$, and the correct condition you want to add to ensure that all the fibers are the same size is that your map be *unramified*.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain a bit more on that how to apply  the condition `unramified' to get the desired result  for the general setting?

Comment: The proof on the algebraic side is since $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ being locally free means it has constant rank, the dimension $d$ of the global sections of $X_y$ over $k(y)$ is the same for all $y$. But for any $x\mapsto y$, we have that the image of $\mathfrak{m}_y$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is $\mathfrak{m}_x^{n_x}$ for some $n_x$, and  when $k(y)$ is algebraically closed, the sum of $n_x$ over all $x$ mapping to some fixed $y$ is exactly this dimension. Unramified gives that $n_x=1$ for all $x$, which forces the number of points over any (closed) $y\in Y$ to be the same since we're over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Can you recommend a reference  on the fact that  "the image of $m_y$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is $m_x^{n_x}$ for some $n_x$"? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it could be something other than $\mathfrak{m}_x^{n_x}$ - all we know is that it's some ideal with radical $\mathfrak{m}_x$ (this comes from finiteness - if the radical is not maximal, then you have an infinite-dimensional amount of global sections) and unramifiedness gives that the (ideal generated by the) image of the maximal ideal is the maximal ideal.